# Does dynamic DSP exist in any game engine today?

Tags: audio

I'm interested in changing audio in my games and adding things like distortion (or you name it) to them dynamically.

For instance: Increase the distortion of a song playing from a radio the closer a player walks to it.

Basically, I want to know if this ability exists in any game engines today. I've programmed my own DSP effects in the past and woukd like to use them on my audio for fun.

What I am not talking about is built in 3d sound or just simply triggering a myriad of pre made sound + effect combinations.

Comment: Would you be interested in this: http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/AudioMixerNativeAudioPlugin.html

Comment: Check out this video I made a while ago showing off some of the stuff you can do in FMOD: http://martindevans.me/assets/FMOD-speed-1.webm

Comment: Very cool. On the surface it looks like it should do the job.